# Breaking down function Logic into sub function

Tags: c++, c

Splitting up functions, into smaller sub function into the code, can effect efficiency of the program?
while reducing cyclomatic complexity of functions i have break down function into smaller parts, and has used helper function and inline functions for it.

```
void functionParent(arguments)
{

    intialCheckFunction(arguments);
    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
    functionThree();
    functionFour();

    return STATUS;
}

void functionOne()
{
   /*follows unary Principle.*/
}
```

My concern is regarding the stack pointer, does a frequent switch of SP reduce efficiency of program drastically or it negligible.
The above functionOne,Two,.. are having UNARY Logic in them.
Kind`enter code here`ly reply in both context, C as well C++

Comment: You've heard of cyclomatic complexity, but not premature optimization? Don't worry about performance unless you need to. If you need to, have metrics in place for quality assurance *before* attempting analysis.

Comment: Yea I have not heard of  premature optimization and Metrics, though after your suggestion i am trying to get updated with it as well.

the real concern to me is, I am using my code , on a 250 - 500 MHZ. 
does this code breaking with using unary principle can affect the efficiency.

Comment: 250-500 MHz tells us hardly anything about what you are doing. However, the point is, unless you have a *reason* to analyze efficiency, you cannot even begin to do so. Optimization does *not* begin with paying attention to small details, that is a waste of effort and tends to corrupt a codebase.

Comment: Thanks, I keep this in mind "Optimization does not begin with paying attention to small details, that is a waste of effort and tends to corrupt a codebase"
I was trying to learn How to use CLEAN CODE and RE FACTOR CODE.
I am working on a SET TOP BOX :
http://www.ti.com/solution/stb-streaming-media-diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I prefer to break up function into smaller functions so that we can reuse it in other places, It is often required during re-factoring. If you are so concerned about the switch and if the function is really small you can mark it as inline. However i don't think having too many functions make such a huge difference in performance of your program.

Comment: In most cases the compiler tries to make inline functions when possible (not sure if some level of optimization should be turned on for this). However (if I'm not wrong) for functions with loops inline wont change anything (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @bcelary Compilers tend to be quite aggressive with inlining, since L1 code cache is not often a scarce resource. Loops do not necessarily affect anything. The critical metric is number of instructions in the function.

Comment: @Potatoswatter thanks for clearing this up. I had heard this some time ago and was not sure this is true.

Answer (score 3):

You should split off logic into its own function whenever you think that it would aid readability: the cost of a function call itself is negligible.

Although it is generally true that calling a function consumes some space and CPU cycles, you shouldn't be worrying about it at all: the instructions involved are optimized beyond belief, and the compiler can inline your code when it sees fit.

**EDIT** (in response to [comment by Potatoswatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243034/breaking-down-function-logic-into-sub-function/11243098#comment14773966_11243098))

One thing you need to be careful is passing parameters, especially in C++, where user code can participate in the process of copying parameters being passed to the function. Passing large `struct`s by value can take more than a few cycles in C, too, so you should pass them by reference or by pointer whenever you can.

Comment: I am working on box having process of 250 - 500 MHZ, can you explain a small bit about CPU Cycle Switch Program Stack.
thanks for valuable comment...

Comment: @Ashutosh 250..500 MHz is still pretty fast: it's 50..100 times faster than the original PC from early eighties :) A function call requires a few cycles per argument that you pass, and a few cycles to push the return address onto a stack and set the program counter to its new value. Similarly, return instruction takes a cycle or two to get the return address off the stack and restore it into the program counter. Overall, this goes very fast, because it is used a lot.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight An argument in C++ might take thousands of cycles it's passed by deep copy, or zero if the caller merely loads it to a location where it was going anyway. And functions are often inlined, as @ Jeeva mentions. Really, there's nothing in particular we can say.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ you can declare inline functions. 
Then no overhead will happen due function call, once code will be replaced in line.

```
inline bool check(args){
    if( some_condiction(args) ){
        return true;
    }
}
inline void functionOne(){...}
inline void functionTwo(){...}
inline void functionThree(){...}
inline void functionFour(){...}

int functionParent(arguments){

    if(check(arguments)==false)
         return FAIL;

    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
    functionThree();
    functionFour();

    return STATUS;
}
```

The current processors architecture execute more than one instruction per time, lets say 5. At a given moment they may be in intermediate stages of completion, lets say 90%,80%,70%,60%,50%. If the first instruction is a function call, all effort made to evaluate the next 4 instructions will be in vain, which will greatly reduce the program execution speed.

Its not needed to care too much about these details, unless you are creating a critical application. Usually compiler is smart enough to inline the needed functions when using optimization flags.